# Ajuda em identificar efeito em site

Tags: jquery, css, html5, parallax

Estou pesquisando em alguns sites e gostei muito do efeito usado neste site https://rocket.chat/ onde ao passar o mouse o efeito interativo se dispersa.
Alguém tem exemplos deste efeito em especifico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nosso amigo Guerra esta certo, o site mencionado usa *[particles](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/)*.
Sua implementação básica é assim:

```js
/* ---- particles.js config ---- */

particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});


/* ---- stats.js config ---- */

var count_particles, stats, update;
stats = new Stats;
stats.setMode(0);
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
count_particles = document.querySelector('.js-count-particles');
update = function() {
  stats.begin();
  stats.end();
  if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array) {
    count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
/* ---- reset ---- */

body {
  margin: 0;
  font:normal 75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #b61924;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

/* ---- stats.js ---- */

.count-particles{
  background: #000022;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  color: #13E8E9;
  font-size: .8em;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 4px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.js-count-particles{
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

#stats,
.count-particles{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#stats{
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.count-particles{
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/assets/_build/js/lib/particles.js"></script>

<!-- particles.js container -->
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<!-- stats - count particles -->
<div class="count-particles">
  <span class="js-count-particles">--</span> particles
</div>

<!-- particles.js lib (JavaScript CodePen settings): https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js -->
```

Além desse tem essa referência legal:
http://soulwire.github.io/sketch.js/
Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

é esse

https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

Não sei bem se aqui é o lugar certo para esse tipo de pergunta, mas ta ai.